# Statistical Significance Dice Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

I think I just need to be pushed to the right formula or algorithm... Imagine you've got a "real" dice which is not an optimal one. And you want to know the confidence intervals for each result. So you rolled the dice a couple of times and get the following absolute probabilities as result:

```
#eyes #occurrences
------------------
1     10
2     11
3     24
4     13
5     14
6     11
```

You actually want to know weather e.g. this 24 times 3 eyes is just a random result or weather it's really more probable. If so, how much more probable is it (for sure)? So I would like to calculate a 99%-confidence interval for the probabilities.

How to calculate this? I probably know this from statistics in university, but just forgot it... so you don't need to go to much into detail. Just need the right formula/algorithm to look for...

Thanks for your help.

--- edit ---
Just to make clear, why I do not just lookup "Confidence Interval" at wikipedia. I would know how to calculate everything if there would be only two cases (e.g. like a coin... 0 and 1). Then I would be able to apply the formula, but I just didn't use such statistics for some years now and just don't see the solution how to reduce the problem.
I just think about taking the result in question (e.g. 3 eyes) as "p" and all other results as "\not p"; does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome can be dichotomized to the events A={you roll a 3} and B={ you roll something other than a 3}.  Let p be the probability of rolling a three.  Then the number of threes rolled is binomial with n=83 (in the example) and p unknown.  Using the binomial distribution you can construct your 99% confidence interval for p.  If the interval doesn't contain 1/6 and the lower bound is above 1/6, you can conclude at the alpha=0.01 level that the die tends to roll more 3s than you would get by chance.

Comment: That's it... thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it's more high level... a bit better adjusted to my needs.

Answer (score 5):

The most common way to do this is to use binomial proportion confidence interval. Let $p$ be the probability that the dice shows 3. This probability is not known but you did an experiment where $24$ out of $83$ trials is 3. Now, your estimated $p$, i.e. $\hat{p}$, is $24/83 = 0.2892$. To get the 95% interval for this estimate, the formula is: $z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$, where $\alpha=5\%$ is the error level, $z_x$ is the $x$ percentile of the standard normal distribution. For $\alpha=5\%$, $z_{1-\alpha/2}=1.96$. And $n$ is the number of trials.

Check [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval) for reference.

Comment: Thanks... even more detail than needed ;-) That saves me even the time looking that formula up.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be independent identically distributed die point random variables, corresponding to the output of each die trow. Let $N_k = \sum_{i=1}^n [ X_i = k ]$ be the number of occurrences of score $k$.

The vector $(N_1, N_2, \ldots, N_6)$ follows a multinomial distribution $\operatorname{Mult}(n, \{p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_6\})$, where $p_1 = \mathbb{P}(X=1)$, $p_2 = \mathbb{P}(X=2)$, etc.

Consider the following statistics:
$$
  S = \left( \frac{N_1}{n} - p_1\right)^2+\left( \frac{N_2}{n} - p_2\right)^2 + \cdots + \left( \frac{N_6}{n} - p_6\right)^2
$$

For the current sample, $n=83$ and $S=0.01957$, and under the null hypothesis of a fair die, the probability 
$$
   \mathbb{P}(S > 0.01957) \approx 0.08
$$
Thus the hypothesis can not be rejected at the 5% level, but can be rejected at 10% level.
[image]

Comment: What the... Ok, thank you very much for that posting. Must have taken you a while to produce it.

Comment: @StefanK. There are many statistics that can be considered, one more complicated than another. The thing to consider is the [power of the statistical test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power).

Comment: @Sasha Well with a p-value=0.08 you would reject at level 0.1 though not at 0.05.

Comment: Because of one-sided test, right?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks, I will change the 95% into 5%.

Comment: @Sasha: I think I'll actually use a Clopper-Pearson-Interval as my number of samples tend to be quite small. And therefore the computational costs are acceptable too. The approximations (as normal distribution) will be probably to inaccurate for e.g. only 49 samples.

Comment: @StefanK. Yes assuming Sasha got 0.08 for a two-sided test you would reject at the one-sided 0.05 level.